# Pure CSS Dropline Menu - second level menu items sit below their parent - but sometimes extend off screen and add horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, menu

I'm working on a pure css menu that consists of four levels

Level 1 and 2 are a dropline menu in style
Levels 3+ are dropdown menus

When you hover over a level 1 menu item, the level 2 menu displays directly below menu item you are currently hovering over.  However if there are lots of menu items on level 2 then the level 2 menu goes off the screen and you see a horizontal scroll bar.

What I want to happen is that if the menu is going to go off the screen I want it to get pushed to the left.  For example, if the menu was 300px long, but there was only 250px between the level 1 menu item and the edge of the page, then the level 2 menu should not be placed directly under the level 1 parent, instead it should be 50px to the left.

I use a nested unordered list for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

For that sort of logic I think you'll need a JavaScript-based solution.

Comment: thanks for your comment - im going down the javascript route at the moment.

I've got it working in Firefox, I have a method that calculates the available pixels on the page, and calculates the size of the span elements within 2nd level <ul>

I'm currently hitting problems with IE6 - if i set the style of the unordered list using 
    parent.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.width = submenuWidth + "px";

Then when I stop hovering over the menu - the border around the second level menus <li>'s and an image within the <li> remain (although the span containing the menu text disappears)